# Search filter query for HTML saved fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have saved my stories title in html formate in database like.

```
<p>My Story</p>
```

Now i want to add search in my website using like query.

If i enter "My" in my search box it's return perfectly but this also return if i enter "p" in my search box so i want to ignore html tag in like query can it's possible?

Please help me to solve my problem.

Here my sql query for search :

```
select `title`, `id` from `stories` where `title` like '%My%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your titles contain the `<p></p>` tags, the following should work:

```
$keyword = "My";
$q = "SELECT  `title`, `id` FROM `stories` WHERE `title` LIKE '%<p>%{$keyword}%</p>%'";
```

Where the `$keyword` is the value you are searching for

Comment: No sometime title have different tags like <h2> or <h3> so it's not working for me

Comment: Then try to use REGEXP such as :
$q = "SELECT * from test WHERE `key` REGEXP '>[^<]*{$keyword}'";
Or study more about it

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need. notice the tags

```
SELECT`title`, `id`
FROM `stories
WHERE `title` 
like '%{keyword}%'
and `title`
not like '%<{keyword}>%'
```

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a23e38/6